# Mobile phone apps - what is MEPE?

Tags: mobile, terminology

What is MEP in the context of mobile phone apps?   From the context, it sounds like some kind of app framework, or portable development environment.

I heard the term, so it is probably spelled hilariously wrong.  It sounded like MEEP or MEPE?

Anyone know this?     Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The comment was not the right answer, but was enough to get me googling in the right direction.   What I heard was "**MEAP**" -- **Mobile Enterprise Applications Platform**.

"MEP" is an abbreviation for Mobile Equipment Personalization (MEP).  Some people say that MEP codes are a BlackBerry-specific feature, but this is actually a GSM feature.  It restricts the use of mobile equipment to specific SIMs. A MEP code may be used to remove the lock, allowing SIM cards from any service provider to be used in the device, if you want to change carriers or travel outside your carrier's service area.

A **MEAP** is a comprehensive suite of products and services that enable development of mobile applications. Wikipedia says the term was coined in a Gartner Magic Quadrant report in 2008 when they renamed their "multi-channel access gateway market".  A key feature of a MEAP is that it has a server that handles all communication with the mobile device.  (So it cannot browse arbitrary websites, except through this proxy, if I understand correctly).

In the days of market capture by smartphone platforms like Android and iOS, MEAPs (from companies like Microsoft) appear as old fashioned as floppy disks.